# WPF image to form picture picturebox

Tags: c#, wpf, image, winforms

I am converting one of the C# WPF based MS kinect example.
To a MS form based version, as I want it to work with an older application.
I'm not really into WPF. I've included the same libraries as in the WPF app to my MS-Forms app (including the PresentationFrameWork)

There is on critical part to me that so far i'm unable to convert.
In the WPF i read:

```
this.Image.Source = this.colorBitmap;
```

Which seams to point to a WPF image (from the image toolbox).
And this reflects the main form

There is no "image"  as in MS forms, the most closest thing to it is picturebox, So i dragged a picturebox on my main form and renamed it to Image
However a picturebox doesn't have a picturebox. source property.
I've tried the image atribute of it.
So now my line reads

```
this.Image.Image = this.colorbitmap;   
// note first image statement is renamed picturebox1
```

However then i get a error

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' to 'System.Drawing.Image' D:\Projects\KinectDepth\KinectDepth\KinectDepth\Form1.cs    114 36  KinectDepth

Does anyone know how to resolve this, since my WPF knowledge is close to zero and i'm a beginner in C#, i find it hard to resolve this issue, since all googling endsup in WPF code in which i am not into at all.

Comment: So where does this 'colorBitmap' image come from? If it's loaded from file, you should just load it as `System.Drawing.Image`.

Comment: @Hans Passant you marked this as a duplicate, but forgot to post the link as where that post is.. can you put a link in your comment. i wasnt able to find it.

Comment: The image comes from the kinect

Comment: I didn't forget, click the link.

Comment: @user613326 The link is on top of the page, at the start of the question. Though I do agree that it's a rather annoying UI design to not put that link in the "marked as duplicate" box, yes.

Comment: Ah found it thanks, sorry for the duplicate